# Tikz/pgfkeys: syntax to define alias content from node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have one node and some auxiliary nodes (labels or less important nodes). For now, if I want to allow the user to customize via style both the main node and the subnode, the user needs to write something like `main/.style={style main node}, subnode1/.style={style subnode}`, but I’d prefer to have it written like `style main node, subnode1/.style={style subnode}`. I’m quite curious: is it possible? I guess I need, somehow, to extract some keys from the main style, or define global somehow `subnode1` as a global style (it seems like each node create a group?).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[options]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
  /first group of styles/.cd,
  cool fill color/.style={fill=pink},
  .search also={/tikz},% order is important
}

\pgfkeys{
  /second group of styles/.cd,
  cool shape/.style={draw,rounded corners},
  label style/.style={},
  label text/.store in=\labelText,
  load defaults/.append style={
    label text={Default label},
  },
  .search also={/tikz},
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myNode}{O{}m}{
  \node[
    inner sep=3mm,
    .search also={/second group of styles,/first group of styles,/tikz},
    /second group of styles/load defaults,
    #1,
    % What is below is both ugly and failing
    /utils/exec={
      %%% Why is this needed?? Can I avoid it?
      \xdef\globalLabelText{\labelText}
      \message{OK}
    },
    "\globalLabelText" {%
      .search also={/first group of styles, /second group of styles,/tizk},      
      % Whyy can't I set the style? Again a scope problem?
      label style
    },
    alias=base
  ]
  {#2};
  \node[anchor=north] at (base.south){
    \globalLabelText
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myNode[
    cool fill color,
    cool shape,
    label text=My label,
    my style/.style={scale=3},
    label style/.style={red, my style},
  ]{A}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
Seems like the pgf filtered library provides tool for this, but my answer got deleted.

Comment: Nowhere near a solution, but `\myNode` is not expandable, whay are you defining it as a `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, a `\node` evaluates its keys inside of a group. I think it's easier to reverse your logic here. Instead of setting your options in the `\node` and fighting Ti*k*Z to get them outside of it, set them outside of the node and forward the relevant stuff to the node.

Comment: @Skillmon regarding expandable I used to get errors when using it without expandable in a tikzcd matrix, not sure why it it was making a difference.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm fine with that, but how could I separate before the part of the node that is made for the first node and the rest?

Comment: There is another issue with your code. The way you're setting up the search path (with `.search also`) doesn't really work, if you use `label style/.style={}` after your `.search also` you'll not change the `label style` of your `/second group of styles`, but instead define a new style in the path `/tikz/label style`.

Comment: @Skillmon I know that I don't know how to properly "import" styles ^^' But I don't know if the issue comes from me or from tikz that is missing the right tools. I created a github issue here https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1284 , do you have some suggestions on the proper way to avoid nested styles? (if so I can maybe create another question)

Comment: If you want to search both paths anyway, why put them use separate paths in the first place? Why not two styles rather than two paths? I don't see how your code relates to what you said you wanted to do.

Comment: @cfr I use path in order to group styles depending on their applications: here `/first group of styles` should only be used in some specific nodes, while `/second group of styles` should be used in other specific nodes, for instance I might want to create a new style `set ellipse width` in `/first group of styles` but this would only make sense in nodes having the shape of an ellipse. And the code I gave just tries to pass information from one node to another node by setting global variables, but it is quite dirty and fails for styles. But apparently the pgf filtered library should solve this.

Comment: `.forward` for the stuff you want to push globally? But why make the global things path-specific in the first place? Why not use sub-paths for the specific stuff and a single path for the global stuff?